# GWT + EJB working?

Tags: gwt, ejb

I want to use EJB in my GWT Application, but I coulnd't find a current Tutorial. I am new to the topic of EJB's and with GWt I have worked the last months. At the moment I have got some RPC Calls in my GWT Application and this works. Is it's possible in GWT to use EJB and if yes would it be difficult to install?

Answer (score 1):

GWT is a client-side framework. It can connect with the server-side i.e. using RPC calls, REST web services or SOAP web services. An EJB on the other hand is a server-side technology which can define several entry-points for its clients.

I would consider creating a proper business logic and create a boundary for it - in form of i.e. RESTful Web Services. This functionality can be tested in well-controlled environment or even in real-life application server.

If this is done, than you just need to create a regular GWT application which 'talks' with EJBs through REST-WS.

Sorry, but I'm not aware of any tutorials about GWT + EJB. There is an example of EJB RESTful implementation at [Adam Bien's weblog](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_13), but if you're really interested in EJB technology and don't know a bit about it, I would recommend to take some decent book first, like [Enterprise Java Beans 3.1](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158033.do).